# search with pagination is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search, pagination

I make it in 1 route with
in route

```
Route::get('/all-students', 'AdminController@studentList')->name('admin.student');
Route::post('/all-students', 'AdminController@searchByClassRoll')->name('search-by-class-roll');
```

in controller funtion student list

```
public function studentList(Request $request)
{
    Session::put('url.intended2', URL::current());
    Session::put('url.intended', URL::previous());

    if (isset($request->class)) {
        if (isset($request->roll)) {
            if ($request->class == 'all') {
                $students = DB::table('students')
                    ->where('roll', '=', $request->roll)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(20);
            } else {
                $students = DB::table('students')
                    ->where('roll', '=', $request->roll)
                    ->where('class', '=', $request->class)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(20);
            }
        } else {
            if ($request->class == 'all') {
                return redirect()->route('admin.student');
            } else {
                $students = DB::table('students')
                    ->where('class', '=', $request->class)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(20);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $students = DB::table('students')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(20);
    }


    return view('admin.student-list')->with('students', $students);
}
```

post method

```
public function searchByClassRoll(Request $request)
{
    $class = $request->class;
    $roll = $request->roll;
    if (isset($request->class)) {
        if (isset($request->roll)) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.student', ['class' => $class, 'roll' => $roll]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('admin.student', ['class' => $class]);
        }
    }
}
```

in blade

```
@if(method_exists($students,'links'))
    {!! $students->links() !!}
@endif
```

normally when I click page 2 it returns
`all-students?page=2`
when I search something `all-students?class=2` and then i click on pagination page it returns again `all-students?page=2` and remove the search data from URL.

form from view

```
<form action="{{ route('search-by-class-roll') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="student_list">
    <div class="row gutters-8">
        <div class="col-4-xxxl col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
            <div class="ui-alart-box">
                <div class="default-alart">
                    <div class="result" role="alert">
                        @if(app('request')->input('class') || app('request')->input('roll'))
                            <a href="{{route('admin.student')}}">See All</a><span> | </span>
                        @endif
                        Showing results {{$students->count()}} of {{$students->total()}} entries
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3-xxxl col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
            <input type="number" name="roll" placeholder="Search by Roll..." class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4-xxxl col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
            <select class="select2 form-control" name="class" required>
                <option value="all">All Classes</option>
                <option value="baby">baby</option>
                <option value="nursery">nursery</option>
                <option value="1">one</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
                <option value="3">three</option>
                <option value="4">four</option>
                <option value="5">five</option>
                <option value="6">six</option>
                <option value="7">seven</option>
                <option value="8">eight</option>
                <option value="9">nine</option>
                <option value="10">ten</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-xxxl col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="fw-btn-fill btn-gradient-yellow">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

i want to made this because I want this in 1 URL just because if someone manually entered the URL with search data he can see the output. but in here I can't get the result with pagination from blade. when I turned into page 2 it remove the search variable from URL. and paginate the whole data. how can I get result with pagination after search?

Comment: You can do the search stuff in one route only. You don't need to go to the post route and then return to get route from another, what are you doing ? it's not the way.

Comment: ohh. can you please give me any docs for the right way?

Comment: Can you post your view filter code as well ?

Comment: please check now I added the form of filtering from blade

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213772/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-tariqul-anik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Coming directly to your controller. You don't need any other route or method you can handle this filtering on same route and in same method.

```
public function studentList(Request $request)
{
    if(!empty($request)){
        $query = $request->all();
       $students = DB::table('students')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
       if(isset($request->class) AND $request->class != '' AND $request->class != 'all')
           $students = $students->where('class', '=', $request->class);
       if(isset($request->roll) AND $request->roll != '')
           $students = $students->where('roll', '=', $request->roll);
       $students = $students->paginate(20);

        return view('admin.student-list', compact('students','query'));
    }

    $students = DB::table('students')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(20);
   return view('admin.student-list', compact('students'));
}
```

> Change few things in your view

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.student') }}" method="get"> change route and method to get
{{ csrf_field() }} //remove this
```

> Below your table inside view write this code. The `appends()` is most important otherwise pagination in your filtered data won't work.

```
@if(isset($query))
  {{ $students->appends($query)->links() }}
@else
  {{ $students->links() }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the simpler way
Just add with your paginated array.

```
{{ $users->withQueryString()->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use append on paginator blade

```
{{$students->appends(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::except('page'))->links()}}
```

Comment: It shows this error : `Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\scl-mgt-update\src\resources\views\admin\student-list.blade.php)`

Comment: `A composer dependency is missing`
`You might be missing a composer dependency. A possible package that was found is illuminate/support.`

`See if this is the package that you need and install it via composer require illuminate/support.`